# Submit Button Javascript closes form on any button not just on submit

Tags: javascript, html

My problem is, that the submit button with javascript onclick event gets triggered even when I click on a field in my form, not just the submit button event.

```
<html>
<body>

<div id="showKontakt" style="position: absolute; top: 40px; left:33%; display:none">
<form class="formoid-solid-blue" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;font-size:14px;font-family:'Roboto',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#34495E;max-width:680px;min-width:150px" method="post"><div class="title"> 
<h2>Kontaktformular</h2></div>
<div class="element-name"><label class="title"><span class="required">*</span></label><span class="nameFirst"><input placeholder=" Vorname" type="text" size="8" name="name[first]" required="required"/><span class="icon-place"></span></span><span class="nameLast"><input placeholder=" Nachname" type="text" size="14" name="name[last]" required="required"/></div>

<button class="submit" style="margin-left: 33%; width: 175px; margin-bottom:20px"><input type="submit" value="Absenden" onclick="closeFrame()"/> 
</button></form>
</div>
<button style="text-align: center;width:60%;margin-left:20%" onclick="setVisibility('showKontakt', 'inline');">Jetzt informieren</button>
<script language="JavaScript">
function setVisibility(id, visibility) {
document.getElementById(id).style.display = visibility;
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function closeFrame() {
document.getElementById("showKontakt").style.display="none";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

expected result: form only closes when I click the submit button.

actual result: form closes also when I click on an input field.

Comment: I doubt that's what's happening. It's just submitting the form, which reloads the whole page.

Comment: Add a console log to the function, you won't see the message when you click on the other button.

Comment: 1. no, I click on eg. name field and it shuts down the form as well (display: none).
2. console doesn't offer any information besides page loading times.

Comment: Can you make a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: If you added `console.log("closeFrame called")` to the function, and you don't see that message in the console, then it's obviously not running that function. The form is being hidden by something else.

Comment: working example above now.
in the stripped down version it works as expected. I need to debug the whole script.

Comment: Why do you have a button inside another button? That makes no sense.

Comment: I have the answer now. Another script was interfering with the forms visibility.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to have a input submit inside a `button`. Try this, since I think that's what you pretend

```js
function closeFrame() {
  document.getElementById("showKontakt").style.display="none";
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm">
  <div id="showKontakt">
    Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Absenden" onclick="closeFrame()"/> 
</form>
```

If you do not want to make the button disappear you may create a button, but outside of the form

```js
function closeFrame() {
  document.getElementById("showKontakt").style.display="none";
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm">
  <div id="showKontakt">
    Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
  </div>
</form>

<button onclick="closeFrame()">Absenden</button>
```